# C++ for-loop wont change variable

Tags: c++, xcode, for-loop, series

**This is my code and I want in-value to change for each iteration (it should decrease as it is a series-loan). I run it in Xcode on a MacOS. **

```
void calculateSeries(){
int loan;
cout<<"Total loan as of today:\n";
cin>> loan;
int series;
cout<<"Number of series\n";
cin>>series;
int interest;
cout<<"Interest:\n";
cin>>interest;
//vector<int> loan_vector(series);
for (int i=1; i<=series; i++){
     double in=(loan/series)+(interest/100)*(loan-(loan/series)*i);

    //cout<<in<<"\n";
    //loan_vector.push_back(in);
        cout<<" Payment year " << i <<" " << in << "\n";}

}
```

My output is this:

```
Total loan as of today:
10000
Number of series
10
Interest:
3
 Payment year 1 1000
 Payment year 2 1000
 Payment year 3 1000
 Payment year 4 1000
 Payment year 5 1000
 Payment year 6 1000
 Payment year 7 1000
 Payment year 8 1000
 Payment year 9 1000
 Payment year 10 1000
```

Answer (score 6):

Your expression `(interest/100)` with `interest` being of type `int` is an integer division and - once the value of `interest` is `<100`, will always result in `0`, since any fractional part of the result will be discarded (cf, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.mul#4) online C++ standard draft):

> **5.6 Multiplicative operators**
>
> 4. ... For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any
>      fractional part discarded

Consequently, term `(interest/100)*(loan-(loan/series)*i)` will be `0`, too, such that your result will be `(loan/series)+0` in each iteration.

Write `(interest/100.)` (note the `.` in `100.` making the second argument a floating point value), such that the term will be a floating point division (instead of an integer division).

BTW: `loan` and `interest` should probably have type `double` instead of `int` anyway.

Comment: Yeah I changed all my variables (except i) to be double and then it worked. Thanks!